# jasmine-ajax not sending out mock request when using browser request

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I am trying to use jasmine plugin mock-ajax to test some ajax requests. The tests correctly identify when an ajax request has been made and can validate such things as the request url. however when following the instructions in the jasmine readme for the return immediately example I cannot get the success callback to be called. I am using browser-request to handle my requests.

The tested code is here

```
var request = require('browser-request');

var loaded = false;

exports.loaded = function () {
    return loaded;
};

exports.fetch = function (url) {
    request(url, function(er, response, body) {
        loaded = true;
    });
};
```

The test code is here

```
var stationData, resoursePath;

describe('Fetch station data after browser load', function () {
    beforeEach(function(){
        resoursePath = 'data/data.json';
        jasmine.Ajax.install();
        stationData = require('../../app/js/station-data.js');
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
    });

    it('should start with no data loaded',function () {
        expect(stationData.loaded()).toBe(false);
    });

    it('should load data from server', function () {
        stationData.fetch(resoursePath);
        expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toBe(resoursePath);
    });

    it('should be loaded after a successful response', function () {
        jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(resoursePath).andReturn({
            "responseText": 'immediate response'
        });
        stationData.fetch(resoursePath);
        expect(stationData.loaded()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The first two test pass but the third one does not.